# Почему Telegram бот не отправляет изображение?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Привет. Пытаюсь отправить картинку в Telegram боте(использую - [эту](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot) библиотеку).

Вот код -

```
 Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, ("Hello!"));
 var FileUrl = @"C:\Users\User\source\repos\BotEducation\BotEducation\Dobbys\hello3.jpg";
 using (var stream = File.Open(FileUrl, FileMode.Open))
 {
     Telegram.Bot.Types.FileToSend fts = new Telegram.Bot.Types.FileToSend();
     fts.Url = new Uri(FileUrl);
     fts.Content = stream;
     fts.Filename = FileUrl.Split('\\').Last();
     Сonsole.WriteLine(fts.Content);
     var rep =  Bot.SendPhotoAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, fts, fts.Filename);
}
```

Но картинка не отправляется. Сообщение "Hello" приходит, а картинка нет и ошибок, тоже, нет. В чем проблема?
Вот, что хранится в fts - [image: fts]

Comment: Новость дня: телеграмм заблокировали. боты не хотят попасть под санкции.

Comment: @TimurMukhortov найс ответ. p.s. если я задаю этот вопрос, мне это не важно.

Answer (score 1):

Все. Разобрался. Вот как надо:

```
  async static void SendHello(MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        var FileUrl = @"C:\Users\User\source\repos\BotEducation\BotEducation\Dobbys\hello3.jpg";
        using (var stream = File.Open(FileUrl, FileMode.Open))
        {
            Telegram.Bot.Types.FileToSend fts = new Telegram.Bot.Types.FileToSend();
            fts.Content = stream;
            fts.Filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUrl);
            await Bot.SendPhotoAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, fts, fts.Filename);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Можно ли сделать отправку фото без асинхронного метода?